# Rails relationship empty, causes rest of the controller to fail on elastic beanstalk but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a rails controller to add an item to a shopping cart. 
The cart is global and set using a before action:

```
    before_action :set_cart, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

```
def create
        shopping_item = ShoppingItem.find(params[:cart_item][:product_id])
        cart_item_selected = nil
        cart_items = @cart.cart_items
        cart_items.each do |cart_item|
            if cart_item.shopping_item == shopping_item
                cart_item_selected = cart_item
            end
        end 

        if not cart_item_selected.nil?
            cart_item_selected.quantity += params[:cart_item][:quantity].to_i
            cart_item_selected.save
        else
            new_item = CartItem.new(shopping_items_id: shopping_item.id,
                quantity: params[:cart_item][:quantity])
            new_item.cart = @cart 
            new_item.save 
            @cart.cart_items << new_item
        end 

        if @cart.save
            redirect_to '/checkout'
        else
            flash[:error] = 'There was a problem adding this item to your cart.'
            redirect_to '/checkout'
        end

        Rescue: 
    end
```

This code works locally but when I deploy to elastic beanstalk it looks like when I'm first trying to add a shopping_item to a cart.

```
cart_items = @cart.cart_items
```

returns nothing and causes

```
if @cart.save
```

to fail.

I'm totally confused by this, maybe I'm reading the logs incorrectly but see them attached. 
[image: Elastic Benastalk Logs]

Comment: What is that random "Rescue:" that you have at the end of the method?

Comment: I would start by using `params.require(:cart_item).require(:product_id)` so that it fails upfront if the param is missing instead of performing `.find` with nil which will cause an error. As to why the record is not saving its most likely a uniqueness validation or some other validation that is not passing. The key difference between local and production may be whats in the DB - not the environment.